# Is it possible to set the page size for a WCF Data Service based on the request type?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I've implemented a WCF Data service that is being used by many different types of clients. I know how to set the page size for the Data service during regular configuration

```
    public class API : DSPDataService<DSPContext>
    {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)            
        {
        //some other config setings...    
        config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 100);
        }
    }
```

This is easy, but it only works during service initialization. Is there also any way to the page size dynamically depending on the incoming request?